# Display todays day of the week, month, day, year in THIS format in PHP?

Tags: php, date

I would like to display this format of the current date using PHP. I have googled and found a few variances of what I want to do but the company I work for wants it specifically in this format to match what they've mailed out.

```
Monday, March 16, 2015
```

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried to look at : www.php.net/date ?

Comment: $today = date("D M j Y");  is what i found and it doesnt display the way i want.

Comment: I left the answer to your question, but next time, PLEASE do some research before just saying "Tell me what to do".

Comment: Reading up on this in the PHP manual on `date` should have been more than easy.

Answer (score 0):

If you looked at the [PHP documentation for `date`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) you'd be able to figure it out very easily:

```
echo date('l, F j, Y');
```

which outputs

> Monday, March 16, 2015

Comment: Thank you. I'm not a coder, just edit what's already there til we can get a coder on payroll.

Comment: @LeoAshcraft if you are not a coder, then don't touch the app. you may make it more messy for your future developers.

Comment: @itachi: I agree with the sentiment, though it is common enough to be asked to do things by an employer that are not ideal `:-)`.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @alfallouji, you should have a look at the php documentation.

Here is what you need:

```
$now = new \DateTime();
echo $now->format('l, F j, Y');
```

Answer (score 0):

The date format string should be "l, F d, Y".

You can display current date in this format as below:

```
<?php
     echo date("l, F d, Y");
?>
```